# UITableViewCell Dynamic height with expandable UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

As I want to create tableview cell that has dynamic height I don't know what height it will take after rendering the content.

And there is a UIView which is hidden. It will render when someone taps on the cell, the UIView is visible.

Now the problem arises when content is larger its starts hiding, and to make that view visible I need the height in Float.

```
// I am using this as a logic for cell expander.
class var expanderHeight : CGFloat { get { return  160 } }
class var defaultHeight :CGFloat { get { return 140 } }

func checkHeight(){
    imageexpander.hidden = (frame.size.height < EaterysTableViewCell.expanderHeight)

}

func watchFrameChanges(){
    if !isObserving {
        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial], context: nil)
    }
}

func ingnoreFrameChanges(){
    if isObserving {
        removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")
        isObserving = false
    }
}
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "frame" {
        checkHeight()
    }
}
```

I have three labels like this:

```
   `|label one|
    |label two|
    |label three|`
```

How do I add constraints so that content of `label one` and `label two` do not get truncated when they have multiple lines (dynamically)?

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yup using auto layouts. I think so there is problem in Constraints. Working on that.

Comment: Yes, you need to manage constraints as per dynamic heights.

Comment: read the last part of the question

Comment: Is your tableview using dynamic cell sizing? If so, what is the priority of your last bottom constraint? My suggestion is to read up on this and do it properly. https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Comment: Thanks Guys Raywenderlich worked :D